# Unable to uncheck a category in a post

Tags: posts, categories

I've created a post and I've checked the 'Jobs' category, but when I save the post, the 'News' category gets automatically checked, as well as the jobs category. It's seemingly impossible stop this post, or any of my future posts for that matter, from being News posts. This hasn't always been happening, but I cannot pinpoint anything that's changed that would start causing this to happen.

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: You will need to debug this on your end. Do you have plugins installed that might effect this? Have you installed or updated anything recently?

Comment: Please, turn off all plugin and set to default theme like twenty fourteen or any twenty... and turn on one by one until you find the error.